# Facebook JavaScript SDK share dialog title with special characters

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've been trying to use Facebook's JavaScript SDK to share. This is an example of the the API function I used.

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'feed',
  link: '',
  title: '',
  description: '',
}, function(response){});
```

In the title field, I have a string with the ™ symbol, but in the dialog, it's displayed a invalid character '?'. I've tried `'&trade;'` or encodings like '%E2%84%A2', '%26trade%3B'. Nothing works.

Has anyone run into this kind of problem before? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.